# how I upgrade my code(build on Tensorflow 1.0.1 python3) to compatible with TF1.2?

Tags: tensorflow

In my code:(works well on tf1.0)

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops  import core_rnn
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops  import core_rnn_cell
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops  import core_rnn_cell_impl
```

report error with tf1.2:
    from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops  import core_rnn
ImportError: cannot import name 'core_rnn'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn_cell
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn_cell_impl
```

in tf1.2 , it should be a replacement like:

```
#cell = core_rnn_cell.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, output_symbols)
cell = tf.nn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, output_symbols)

#_, enc_state = core_rnn.static_rnn(cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtype, scope=scope)
_, enc_state = tf.nn.static_rnn( cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtype, scope=scope)

#y = linear(query, attention_vec_size, True)
y = rnn_cell_impl._linear(query, attention_vec_size, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Tensorflow 1.2 changelog](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.2.0):

> Many of the RNN functions and classes that were in the tf.nn namespace
>   before the 1.0 release and which were moved to tf.contrib.rnn have now
>   been moved back to the core namespace. This includes RNNCell,
>   LSTMCell, GRUCell, and a number of other cells. These now reside in
>   tf.nn.rnn_cell (with aliases in tf.contrib.rnn for backwards
>   compatibility). The original tf.nn.rnn function is now
>   tf.nn.static_rnn, and the bidirectional static and state saving static
>   rnn functions are also now back in the tf.nn namespace.

It looks like you'll need to update your code to use `tf.nn.rnn`, `tf.nn.rn_cell` and I'm fairly certain you shouldn't be concerned with any '*_impl' file, which is supposed to be hidden from the API and might change anytime.

Comment: Please edit the question, comments are the worst place to put code snippets as the formatting is always lost..

Comment: I finally fixed it out by "find"+"grep" the tensorflow source code to find the correct name path. thanks Gphilo